# Rearrange elements outputted by comment_form()

Tags: customization, order, comment-form

I'm currently developing a custom theme from scratch.

In the past week, I've been trying to change the order of the HTML elements output by the `comment_form()`.

I basically don't know any PHP, and I was unable to find information on the `comment_form()` that successfully covers how to rearrange the layout of its output, including the WordPress Codex.

Can anyone please explain how to rearrange the elements outputted by the `comment_form()`, preferably without having to be proficient in PHP and the inner workings of WordPress?

Please don't provide solutions that rely on re-positioning elements with CSS; this can't be the way you're intended to customize the output.

If it turns out there isn't an optimal way to achieve this, would it then be possible to customize `comments.php` without using the `comment_form()`, like you would before the function was introduced?

The following links cover some of the most relevant methods I've tried. They either don't work at all or don't achieve the correct result:

http://freetexthost.com/wplcq61i3d

(Sorry, but I'm not allowed to post more than two links directly in the post.)

Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, I used it to try focus attention on the actual questions in order to streamline the post. I'm removing it now.

Comment: I'm not expecting CSS solutions, I specifically requested not to receive any, based on replies to previous questions on the subject that contained it, but that's good to hear.

Answer (score 2):

### Re-arranging the comment fields

The *comment text area* has been [moved](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/09/25/changes-to-fields-output-by-comment_form-in-wordpress-4-4/) to the top in WordPress 4.4:

[image: default 4.4]

What if we prefer the old setup, where it was at the bottom?

### Re-arranging the `author`, `url` and `email` comment fields

We can modify the display order, of the *author*, *url* and *email* fields, with:

```
/**
 * Re-arranging the author, url and email comment fields
 */
add_filter( 'comment_form_defaults', function( $defaults )
{
    $_defaults = [];

    // Re-arrange the fields to your needs:
    $fields = [ 'author', 'url', 'email' ];

    foreach( $fields as $field )
        $_defaults['fields'][$field] = $defaults['fields'][$field]; 

    return $_defaults;
} );
```

but we will have to find another approach to re-order the *comment text area* an the *submit button*.

### Custom Workaround

To re-arrange all five comment fields, we can use the custom `wpse_comment_fields` filter:

```
add_filter( 'wpse_comment_fields', function( $fields )
{       
    return $fields;
} );
```

in the `functions.php` file or in a plugin.

### Example: `Author` field at top

Let's move the *author* field to the top:

```
/**
 * Display the 'author' comment field at top:
 */
add_filter( 'wpse_comment_fields', function( $fields )
{
    // Re-arrange fields
    $fields = [ 'author', 'comment', 'url', 'email', 'submit' ];

    return $fields;
} );
```

The comment form will then display as:

[image: custom 1]

### Example: `Comment` field at the bottom and remove the `Url` field

Here we display the *comment* field at the bottom and remove the *url* field:

```
/**
 * Display the 'comment' field at the bottom and remove the 'url' field:
 */
add_filter( 'wpse_comment_fields', function( $fields )
{
    // Re-arrange fields
    $fields = [ 'email', 'author', 'comment', 'submit' ];

    return $fields;
} );
```

Then the comment form will show:

[image: custom 2]

### Demo Plugin

Here's our demo plugin that supports the `wpse_comment_fields` filter (PHP 5.4+):

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Rearrange Comment Fields
 * Plugin URI:  http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/207449/26350
 * Author:      Birgir Erlendsson (birgire)
 * Description: Support for rearranging the comment fields: 'comment', 'auhtor', 'url', 'email' and 'submit' through the 'wpse_comment_fields' filter.
 * Version:     0.0.1
 */

add_action( 'comment_form_before', function()
{
    if( class_exists( 'WPSE_Rearrange_Comment_Fields' ) )
    {
        $fields = apply_filters( 
            'wpse_comment_fields', 
            [ 'comment', 'author', 'url', 'email', 'submit' ]
        );

        $o = new WPSE_Rearrange_Comment_fields;
        $o->set_fields( $fields )
          ->init();
    }
});

class WPSE_Rearrange_Comment_Fields
{
    private $html       = [];
    private $defaults   = [];
    private $fields     = [];

    public function set_fields( array $fields )
    {
        $this->fields = $fields;
        return $this;
    }

    public function init()
    {
        // Default
        $this->defaults = [ 'comment', 'author', 'url', 'email', 'submit' ];

        // Check for defaults
        if( empty( $this->fields ) )
            $this->fields = $this->defaults;

        // Hooks
        add_action( 'comment_form',                 [$this, 'display'],                     PHP_INT_MAX );
        add_filter( 'comment_form_field_comment',   [$this, 'comment_form_field_comment'],  PHP_INT_MAX );
        add_filter( 'comment_form_submit_field',    [$this, 'comment_form_submit_field'],   PHP_INT_MAX );
        foreach( [ 'author', 'url', 'email' ] as $field )
            add_filter( "comment_form_field_{$field}",  [$this, 'comment_form_field'], PHP_INT_MAX );       
    }

    public function display()
    {
        // Display fields in the custom order                   
        $html = '';
        foreach( (array) $this->fields as $field )
        {
            if( in_array( $field, $this->defaults ) ) 
                $html .= $this->html[$field]; 
        }
        echo $html;
    }

    public function comment_form_submit_field( $submit_field )
    {
        $this->html['submit'] = $submit_field;
        return '';
    }

    public function comment_form_field_comment( $comment_field )
    {
        $this->html['comment'] = $comment_field;
        return '';
    }

    public function comment_form_field( $field )
    {
        $key = str_replace( 'comment_form_field_', '', current_filter() );
        $this->html[$key] = $field;
        return '';
    }

} // end class
```