# Custom comment-field form arrangement

Tags: comment-form

How can I move my custom comment fields above the comment field?

Currently i am using hooks `comment_form_after_fields` and `comment_form_logged_in_after`. Unfortunately due to Wordpress 4.4 [changes](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/09/25/changes-to-fields-output-by-comment_form-in-wordpress-4-4/), when a user is not logged-in the comment field is shown first and then the 'Name' and 'email' default fields. This means my custom fields are below the default fields.

I have  'comment-title' and 'rating'fields that I need above the comment field.

Is there another Hook I could use? If not should I resort to editing a comment comments.php?

Comment: [Here's](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/136245/rearrange-elements-outputted-by-comment-form/207449#207449) one kind of  approach that might help?

Comment: @birgire thanks for that, but it only talks about the default fields. I want my custom fields to be above the comment field and available to logged-in/out users.

Comment: You need to show your current code. Else it's guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you could use the `comment_form_field_comment` filter to inject content (extra fields or whatever) above the comment field:

```
function comment_form_field_comment_add_field( $field ) {
    $new_field = '<p class="comment-form-extra"><label for="extra">Extra Field</label> <input id="extra" name="extra" type="text" value="" size="30" aria-required="true" required="required"></p>';

    $field = $new_field . $field;

    return $field;
}
add_filter( 'comment_form_field_comment', 'comment_form_field_comment_add_field' );
```

You could also switch that around to put the new/extra field below the comment field:

```
$field = $field . $new_field;
```

Screenshot with twentyfourteen: http://b.ustin.co/1dvho

Comment: Will these fields also show when the user is logged in?

Comment: @Adzay yes, they should, as it's a filter on the comment field which displays for those logged in and not logged in. Obviously, if you wanted to only make the field invisible to logged out users (or vice-versa), you could update the snippet to wrap the additional field in a `is_user_logged_in()` check.